# Trying to Minimize Wages/Workers Problem Using SciPy Optimize

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I just recently learned about PuLP and now I am trying to learn about SciPy Optimize. If I have a simple dataframe, like the one below, how can I optimize/minimize wages, workers, or both?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as sco
from io import StringIO



with StringIO(
'''Time Windows,Shift 1,Shift 2,Shift 3,Shift 4,Workers Required
    6:00 - 9:00,      1,      0,      0,      1,            55.0
   9:00 - 12:00,      1,      0,      0,      0,            46.0
  12:00 - 15:00,      1,      1,      0,      0,            59.0
  15:00 - 18:00,      0,      1,      0,      0,            23.0
  18:00 - 21:00,      0,      1,      1,      0,            60.0
  21:00 - 24:00,      0,      0,      1,      0,            38.0
   24:00 - 3:00,      0,      0,      1,      1,            20.0
    3:00 - 6:00,      0,      0,      0,      1,            30.0
      Wage_Rate,    135,    140,    190,    188,             0.0''') as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, skipinitialspace=True, index_col='Time Windows')

is_shift = df.columns.str.startswith('Shift')
is_wage = df.index == 'Wage_Rate'
shifts = df.loc[~is_wage, is_shift]
wage_rate = df.loc[is_wage, is_shift].squeeze()
workers_req = df.loc[~is_wage, 'Workers Required']

# create arrays
min_wages = wage_rate.values
min_workers = workers_req.values


# add constraints
constraints = (min_workers, min_wages)

# min 0 workers and increase in 10% increments up to 100%
# there is no 10% of a worker, but .1 could be multiplied by 'workers_req'
bound = (0.0,.1)

bounds = tuple(bound for item in range(min_workers))
result = sco.minimize(method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds, constraints=constraints)
```

Everything compiles, up to the last two lines of code. When I try to set 'bounds' to 'min_workers', I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[101], line 1
    bounds = tuple(bound for item in range(min_workers))

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index


bounds = tuple(bound for item in range(min_workers))
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[102], line 1
    bounds = tuple(bound for item in range(min_workers))

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

So, I'm not even sure if this is the right approach, but it seems pretty close. Basically, I am trying to minimize wages/workers, and set this as the constraint. How can I make this work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to figure out how to optimize worker's schedules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75973787/trying-to-figure-out-how-to-optimize-workers-schedules)

Comment: This seems like a duplicate.