# Trying to figure out how to optimize worker's schedules

Tags: optimization, scipy, mathematical-optimization, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have this basic scenario of workers times, shifts, and wage rates (described below). I understand how to solve this as a Linear Programming problem, but how can I use SciPy Optimize to solve / minimize the amount paid to workers?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as sco
from io import StringIO



with StringIO(
'''Time Windows,Shift 1,Shift 2,Shift 3,Shift 4,Workers Required
    6:00 - 9:00,      1,      0,      0,      1,            55.0
   9:00 - 12:00,      1,      0,      0,      0,            46.0
  12:00 - 15:00,      1,      1,      0,      0,            59.0
  15:00 - 18:00,      0,      1,      0,      0,            23.0
  18:00 - 21:00,      0,      1,      1,      0,            60.0
  21:00 - 24:00,      0,      0,      1,      0,            38.0
   24:00 - 3:00,      0,      0,      1,      1,            20.0
    3:00 - 6:00,      0,      0,      0,      1,            30.0
      Wage_Rate,    135,    140,    190,    188,             0.0''') as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, skipinitialspace=True, index_col='Time Windows')

is_shift = df.columns.str.startswith('Shift')
is_wage = df.index == 'Wage_Rate'
shifts = df.loc[~is_wage, is_shift]
wage_rate = df.loc[is_wage, is_shift].squeeze()
workers_req = df.loc[~is_wage, 'Workers Required']

# create arrays
min_wages = wage_rate.values
min_workers = workers_req.values


# add constraints
constraints = (min_workers, min_wages)

# min 0 workers and increase in 10% increments up to 100%
# there is no 10% of a worker, but .1 could be multiplied by 'workers_req'
bound = (0.0,.1)

bounds = tuple(bound for item in range(min_workers))
result = sco.minimize(method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds, constraints=constraints)
```

Everything compiles, up to the last two lines of code. When I try to set 'bounds' to 'min_workers', I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[11], line 2
    bounds = tuple((0,1) for asset in range(shifts))

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: A constraint has the form g(x) >= 0 (or == 0), where g evaluates your constraint for the current point x. So your constraints (a tuple of two numpy arrays) don't make sense. You need to pass your constraints as Linear/NonlinearConstraint objects or as dicts, see the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) for more details.  In addition, you need to pass an objective function . If you only want to find a feasible point, you can use the objective function `lambda x: 0`.

Comment: Ok, so i just updated the constraints, based on your comment, and that seems to work, but now I'm getting an error with the bounds. How can I make this work?

Comment: Well, assuming you want to enforce 0.0 <= x_i <= 0.1 for each optimization variable x_i, you could do `bounds = [(0.0, 0.1) for _ in range(min_workers.size)]`.

Comment: If you want to use scipy only (why?), it's still best to frame this as a linear program; just call into `milp`

Comment: I know this can be solved using a linear programming. I am trying to learn how to use SciPy. I updated the code to what you see below, but I'm not getting any solution.

x0 = wage_rate.values
min_workers = workers_req.values

bounds = [(0.0, 0.1) for _ in range(min_workers.size)]
result = sco.minimize(method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds, *x0)

Comment: You've got a misprinting suggestion)) `range` expects `int`. You don't need to range over an array. Simply `bounds = tuple(bound for _ in min_workers)`. But you when will need to define the objective function for `minimize`.